# Sharepoint client object model "File not found" Powershell

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, csom

I have some issue when i try to create a folder, but the same issue come out when i try create file too.

this is a sample of my code :

```
$web_sp = $session_sp.Web
$session_sp.Load($web_sp)
$session_sp.ExecuteQuery()

$folder = $web_sp.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(($urlGed.Valeur+'/'+$ObjGed.Valeur+'/Commandes'))
$session_sp.Load($folder)
$session_sp.ExecuteQuery()

# at this moment if I check $folder.ServerRelativeUrl it returns the good url so I thinks it means it's loaded correctly

$folder.Folders.Add('NewFolder') # Here no exeption

$session_sp.Load($folder) #Folder or Folder.Folders
$session_sp.ExecuteQuery()
```

at the last ExecuteQueryan an exception has occurred ("File not found")

(When I use the Sharepoint web page I can create folder and file so I think I have the acces rigth)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$myNewFolder = $folder.Folders.Add('NewFolder') # Newly created folder return to $myNewFolder variable

$session_sp.Load($myNewFolder) # Load this variable for the new folder
$session_sp.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i have the same result ("File not found") Exception.

Comment: Does your expression `($urlGed.Valeur+'/'+$ObjGed.Valeur+'/Commandes')` yield a correct server relative URL to the Commandes folder?

Comment: Yes when a verify in my web browser it's a good URL. Thanks for your help btw